# Unable to export pdf using JsPdf

Tags: vue.js, jspdf

Hi I want to Export html to pdf, I have used jsPDF for this. I tried different methods, either that produced a blank pdf or didn't exported PDF.
Can someone help?

**Template**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="bill" ref="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="d-inline-block">Test</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Method 1**

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
       const contentHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;
        pdf.html(contentHTML, {
        callback: function(pdfSave) {
          pdf.save("test.pdf");
        }
```

> Produced blank Pdf

**Method 2**

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

var pdf = new jsPDF();
       const contentHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;
       pdf.fromHTML(contentHTML, 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
        pdf.save("test.pdf");
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

**Method 3**

```
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    const contentHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;

    pdf.addHTML(contentHTML, function () {
    pdf.save("test.pdf");
    });
```

> Do not export PDF. In short, not working

Would appreciate if someone could help. Thanks!